# Upgrade libxml and libxml2 in linux server

Tags: linux

Currently, I already have libxml version 2.6.16 in the server. We have a new project to be deployed which uses Symfony Framework and uses a higher version of libxml and it is at least 2.6.21. In addition, we are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4. My question now is what should I do and if needed to upgrade how can I upgrade it?

**UPDATE**
After running this command `rpm -Uvh libxml2*.rpm`, I got this errors :

```
warning: only V3 signatures can be verified, skipping V4 signature
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) setools-2.3-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxslt-1.1.11-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xmlsec1-1.2.6-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.6-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonobo-2.8.0-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) alchemist-1.0.34-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) shared-mime-info-0.15-10.1.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) GConf2-2.8.1-1.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libglade2-2.4.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomecanvas-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) pygtk2-libglade-2.4.0-2.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-vfs2-2.8.2-8.6.EL4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonoboui-2.8.0.99cvs20040929-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeui-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-bonobo-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) Omni-0.9.1-7.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) foomatic-3.0.2-3.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gstreamer-0.8.7-4.EL.0.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libcroco-0.6.0-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libsoup-2.2.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) scrollkeeper-0.3.14-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libwmf-0.2.8.3-5.7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gstreamer-plugins-0.8.5-1.EL.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gtkhtml2-2.6.2-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) firefox-1.5.0.12-0.3.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) ggv-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-desktop-2.8.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-gtkhtml2-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) krb5-auth-dialog-0.2-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgsf-1.10.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) evolution-data-server-1.0.2-14.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-panel-2.8.1-8.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-pilot-2.0.12-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) usermode-gtk-1.74-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) rhn-applet-2.1.25-22.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeprint22-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeprintui22-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gpdf-2.8.2-7.7.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) librsvg2-2.8.1-1.el4.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) eel2-2.8.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gdm-2.6.0.5-7.rhel4.15.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) kdelibs-3.3.1-9.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxklavier-1.02-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-kerberos-0.3.3-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xscreensaver-4.18-5.rhel4.14.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) file-roller-2.8.1-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gconf-editor-2.8.0-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-keyring-manager-0.0.3-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-media-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-netstatus-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-applets-2.8.0-9.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-system-monitor-2.7.0-8.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-terminal-2.7.3-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-utils-2.8.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gok-0.11.8-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgail-gnome-1.1.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnopernicus-0.9.12-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) NetworkManager-gnome-0.3.1-4.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) vino-2.8.1-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gtksourceview-1.1.0-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gthumb-2.4.2-7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) eog-2.8.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gedit-2.8.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-2.8.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) control-center-2.8.0-12.rhel4.5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-volume-manager-1.1.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-session-2.8.0-7.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-cd-burner-2.8.3-6.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-media-0.8.1-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) desktop-printing-0.17-3.EL.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) yelp-2.6.4-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) perl-XML-LibXML-Common-0.13-7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) perl-XML-LibXML-1.58-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxml2-devel-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonoboui-devel-2.8.0.99cvs20040929-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) glade2-2.6.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) bug-buddy-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) seamonkey-1.0.9-2.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) devhelp-0.10-0.8.el4.i386
        libxml2 = 2.6.16 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2 = 2.6.16 is needed by (installed) libxml2-devel-2.6.16-10.i386
```

How can I possibly solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 4 is very outdated, so you are unlikely to find a libxml-2.6.21 designed specifically for it. However, RPMs are available directly from xmlsoft:

ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/

If you download a source rpm, you should be able to compile it for your version of RHEL.

In theory, a rebuild of the source RPM should be simple:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild /path/to/libxml2-2.7.2-1.src.rpm
```

Once the source RPM is compiled to an RPM appropriate RPM for your server, install/upgrade it as usual.

```
rpm --upgrade /path/to/libxml2-2.7.2-1.yourARCH.rpm
```

Comment: where should I install my download libxml2?

Comment: i found the current version here : `/usr/share/doc/libxml2-2.6.16`

Comment: by the way i just download the libxml here: `http://xmlsoft.org/sources/` since i cannot open the link you posted

Comment: can you explain more your answer? thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you tell me what you have tried? did you bulid the rpm? have you tried the upgrade?

Comment: yes I tried this command `rpm -Uvh libxml2*.rpm` and got failed dependencies error ,, i'll just update my post